# why is this perlinnoise displacement filter not updating?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript, actionscript-2

i got this script from [this tutorial](http://www.pixelhivedesign.com/tutorials/Realistic+Flash+Water+Effect/). I tried to convert it from AS2 to AS3, but it seems like the displacement filter is only applied once for some reason. After that, the bitmap isn't updated ...

```
    var myBitmap:BitmapData = new BitmapData(1000,600,false,0);
    var pt = new Point(0,0);
    var mpoint = new Point(0,0);
    var myDispl = new DisplacementMapFilter(myBitmap, mpoint,1,2,10,30);
    var myList = new Array();
    myList.push(myDispl);
    water_mc.filters = myList;
    var i = 1;
    this.addEventListener("enterFrame", perlin );

    function perlin(evt)
    {
        var filterList = water_mc.filters;
        var offset = new Array();
        offset[1] = new Object(); 
        offset[1].x = i * 15;
        offset[1].y = i/8 * 15;
        filterList.mapBitmap = myBitmap;
        myBitmap.perlinNoise(45,5,3,50,true,false, 7,true,offset);

        water_mc.filters = filterList;
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to apply the filter everytime since you are not making any changes to the filter in the Enter_Frame Handler. Also the DisplacementMapFilter can be directly applied to your movieclip. I have made some code changes to the code you pasted.

```
//waterImage is a Bitmap Object. If you embed the object it will be a bitmap so no issues
// typecast it if necessary. If you use a loader to load your image, then you can get the bitmap
// using loader.content after the loader has done loading.
var mpoint = new Point(0,0);
var myDispl = new DisplacementMapFilter(null, mpoint,1,2,10,30);
waterImage.filters = [myDispl];
var i = 1;
this.addEventListener("enterFrame", perlin );

function perlin(evt)
{
    waterImage.bitmapData.perlinNoise(45,5,3,50,true,false, 7,true,[i*15,(i/8)*15]);
    i++;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to work, or I'm stil missing something... could you show complete code please? What exactly is waterImage and myBitmap in your code ?

Comment: did you read the comments before the code? I have explained what waterImage is.
There was an error earlier in my code. I have made changes to fix this. sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

This

`this.addEventListener("enterFrame", perlin );`

is incorrect.

Actionscript 3 doesn't use `"enterFrame"` like AS2 does. The line you're looking for is this:

`this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, perlin);`

You will need to import the proper class, `flash.events.Event`, for this to work properly. Additionally, is this a frame script, or is it part of the document class definition? Make sure that you're writing your code correctly, depending on where you put it.